# java XML to map not working

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have the following XML:

```
<myroot>
<id>1</id>
<doc>im a doc</doc>
<src>sys</src>
</myroot>
```

and I want to be able to parse everything inside "myroot" in a map. So for the above i want my function to return a map as follows {id=1, doc=im a doc, src=sys}
I'm using DOM so please provide only a DOM suggestion, here's the code I have:

```
//Code to init the Document here.            
....
NodeList root = document.getChildNodes();   //up here i should have myroot
NodeList elements = root.item(0).getChildNodes();  //here i should get all the nested items i want to map
for ( int x = 0; x < elements.getLength(); x++ ) {         
  map.put(elements.item(x).getNodeName(), elements.item(x).getNodeValue());
}
```

What I'm getting however is this map is a #text map that I don't need and all my values are null!:
{#text= , doc=null, id=null, src=null}

Can anyone help please?

Comment: `getChildNodes()` includes all nodes, not just elements.

Comment: yes it's just a variable, so how do I change my code to work? the node holds the name and value, i don't understand why getNodeValue() returns null.

Comment: What you want is `getTextContent()` and not `getNodeValue()`, or you may retrieve the first child before like so: `getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, using getFirstChild().getNodeValue() worked! i can't use TextContext().... a solved it using a combination of Alex and emin's solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
        NodeList nList = doc.getChildNodes();
        NodeList elements = nList.item(0).getChildNodes();


        for (int temp = 0; temp < elements.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = elements.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Node name: " + eElement.getNodeName() + " \tValue: " + eElement.getTextContent());


            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution... what can I use instead of getTextContent()?? I'm using java 1.4 so i'm getting a: "The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Element"

Comment: use eElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() instead of eElement.getTextContent()